# React native async await white screen

Tags: react-native, asynchronous

I can't seem to find any answers online about this, but has anyone ever run into a problem with asynchronous functions causing a white screen on install?

I know the async await part of this code is causing the issue:

```
async syncData(){
    await fetchSomeData()
    navigate("to my first page");
{
```

The fetchSomeData() function fetches data from a url and returns a promise.

The app starts in a loading page where the above fetching is. It works fine when I don't have async await, but it doesn't wait for the data to finish fetching before navigating. The weird thing to me is that this only happens on the first install of the app.

edit:
I should try and clarify. The async await works in the sense that it waits properly for the function fetchSomeData() to do its thing. And when I build locally (with starting a metro server and debugging the app on my phone), the app works as intended. But when I build an APK, the async await in this section causes the app to crash and display a white screen (but only after the first install). If I remove the async await, it won't cause a white screen, but obviously, it doesn't wait for the data to fetch.